# Databinding Repeater Issue

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, repeater

Im trying to bind My query to two items in my default page.  I think the DataBinder.Eval should be in blue also. Its not. Can you tell me what im doing wrong in the code below. Im getting a sintax error that says.

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Default.aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCommenter" runat="server" Text="<%DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CommentersName") %>"></asp:Label>
```

Code Behind

```
 BSComments GetComments = new BSComments();
 DataTable DAGetComments = GetComments.GetCommentsByPicIDs(PicId);
 Repeater1.DataSource = DAGetComments;
 Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Text='<% #Eval("CommentersName") %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

try use

```
Text='<%DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CommentersName") %>'
```

Notice the `'` and `"`, what we do in javascript